# Generating tests in emacs buttercup

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs-buttercup

I have a emacs buttercup tests:

```
(describe
"Test"
(defun test-some (test-string actual expected)
  (let ((act actual) (exp expected))
    (it test-string
        (expect act
                :to-equal
                exp))))

(test-some
  "should be equal"
  1
  1))
```

However, it gives me

```
Test should be equal
error: (void-variable act)
```

when executed. The string is there, so at least the `test-string` is
passed correctly. However, there seems to be a problem with the other
arguments.

Relevant section in the manual: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/emacs-buttercup/#its-just-functions

Comment: You need to look at the code. Does it use `lexical-binding`? the error says that `act` is not bound, which indicates that `(expect act...)` is evaluated in another context from the lexical one where it appears.

Comment: Can confirm, works with `lexical-let`.

Comment: So use `lexical-let` or put it in a file where you turn on `lexical-binding` (if you have a recent enough Emacs version). If you do the latter then load the file (or the byte-compiled file) - do not just select some of the code and evaluate it, because that will not pick up the `lexical-binding` declaration from the file header.

Comment: @Drew wanna write it out as an answer?

Comment: No; I don't have the time to check the buttercup code for details etc. You should have enough to go on, I think. If not, perhaps someone will spell it out better with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example function:

```
(cl-defun indent-and-compare (test-string file-name &key (uncompleted-indent 4))
  (lexical-let ((act (concat file-name "-actual.nim")) (exp (concat file-name "-expected.nim"))
                (indent uncompleted-indent))
    (it test-string
        (setq nim-uncompleted-condition-indent indent)
        (insert-file-contents-literally act)
        (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))

        (expect (buffer-string)
                :to-equal
                (file-to-string exp)))))
```

Via https://github.com/nim-lang/nim-mode/blob/ada2f827507397a8f20587af7c07d4de26e96394/tests/test-indent.el#L10-L20